# Problema sumar fecha con DATE_ADD sql en laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Hola amigos tengo un problema a la hora de sumar los días de una fecha con **DATE_ADD** mediante DB RAW (laravel), mi problema reside en que necesito poder sumar los decimales de una variable que actúa como intervalo en **DATE_ADD**, es decir tengo una variables que se llama **dias_previstos** el cual en este momento es **1,5** **(cuenta como día y medio )**, por algún motivo el **0,5 (medio día )** se lo salta y solo suma el **1 (día)**. Necesito que se pueda sumar el **0,5(medio dia)** al calendario para que se redondee y pase de día, es decir si es día 1 y dias_previstos es igual a 1.5 el resultado debería ser día 3.

> \DB::raw('DATE_ADD(proyectos.inicio, INTERVAL proyectos.dias_previstos DAY) as finObrasDistribucion'),

**PD:** Básicamente necesito que proyectos.dias_previstos haya alguna manera de poder sumar la parte decimal.